# Lie algebras over non-algebraically closed field

Tags: reference-request, lie-algebras

Could someone recommend a book on Lie algebras over a not-necessarily algebraically closed field? I am particularly interested in the representation theory, so it should contain all the usual results about highest-weight modules. For various reasons, Bourbaki is not desirable, and http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/LAG.pdf refers its proofs to Bourbaki too often for my liking.

Comment: Maybe you should reconfigure your liking?

Comment: Bourbaki's volumes on Lie algebras are a standard reference for the subject, and it is for good reason that everybody refers to them. If one's liking becomes an obstacle to taking advantage of something of value, then  changing that preference can be in one's best interest.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Very well then. I'll try and get used to Bourbaki this semester. But I recently found Hilgert and Neeb's *Structure and Geometry of Lie Groups* and it's also what I'm looking for.